# ImportError: No module named Selenium, any suggestions?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, robotframework

I am in the process of learning the RobotFramework from an absolute beginners point.
I have had experience creating automation scripts using ruby-watir and gherkin. As well as automation in c#.

However I am simply stumped with even the setup of RobotFramework in Pycharm.

I have installed all the packages
I deemed necessary 
 -including selenium/RobotFramework /RobotFramework-selenium2library.

My Python.exe and scripts are in the correct directory as well as the environment variables being added.

However when I run :

```
from lettuce import *
from behave import *
from Selenium import webdriver


@step("I am on the web")
def step_impl(context):
context.browser = webdriver.Firefox

pass
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Jordan/PycharmProjects/RbtFrameWork/features/steps/Test_steps.py", line 3, in <module> 
     from Selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named Selenium
```

I imagine it's something to do with the installation location of my selenium - which I have installed through pip

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Python` is case sensitive so instead of `from Selenium import webdriver` you should use `from selenium import webdriver`